# After Building assigned.apk is not showing on bin/Andriod/release folder am using visual Studio 2013 apche cordova?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, configuration, apk, visual-studio-cordova

i am created visual studio 2013 cordova application.when i run locally working fine.i tried to generate apk file it will be created on bin folder.but my problem is with in a bin folder just showing VSBuildinfo file not showing apk files.How to fix this problem.i am struggling for last one week?still i can't solve this issue.